# write a table in "for loop" (R)

Tags: r, bioinformatics, sequences, fasta

I have many sequences in a text file. I import these sequences using "read.fasta" function.
I use "for loop" to create table of nucleotides frequency for each sequence and use "write.table" to have an output. But it create a file per each sequence(many output file and each file have table of a sequence).
I search for a commands to create a file that have all tables.
note: "mydata.txt" is a file contain many sequence with fasta format

```
file=read.fasta(file="mydata") 
for (i in seq_along(file))
{
NucleotidesFrequency=table(file[[i]])
print(NucleotidesFrequency)
write.table(NucleotidesFrequency, paste(i, (".txt"), sep=""),sep="\t") 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `rbind` (see `?rbind` for details):

```
## create example data
set.seed(1)
s <- list(sample(LETTERS[1:4], size=20, replace=T), sample(LETTERS[1:4], size=20, replace=T))

## call table for each item in the list
l <- lapply(s, table)
l
#[[1]]
#A B C D 
#4 5 5 6 
#[[2]]
#A B C D 
#5 7 4 4

## using rbind to create a matrix
d <- do.call(rbind, l)
d
#    A B C D
#[1,] 4 5 5 6
#[2,] 5 7 4 4

## write it into a file
write.table(d, "file.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't use rbind in for loop! The outputs of for loop in my commands are tables, I want to have all of these tables in a text file.

Comment: @ToobaAbbassi: What is the difference between all your tables and my matrix?

Comment: @ sgibb: There is no deference but I want to merge them as a table. Your suggestion solved my problem. Thanks a lot.